# How can I organizing parts of a code file into titled, collapsible, bordered UI containers in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I separate different parts of code in any file into separate modules, simply for easier visual understanding of the different parts, preferably collapsible too- and supporting any code language in VS Code?

For example, say I have a CSS file with five rules for styling the navigation bar and three rules for styling the footer. I would like to be able to define the navbar rules as one module, titled "Navigation Bar Rules", and make another module for the footer, titled "Footer Rules".

All of the code would still be visible on the page, but there would be some visual separation between all the modules, for example each module is displayed in a bordered container, and you could easily see the module title. And the modules would be collapsible.

How can this be done?

Comment: Note to other users: I have removed the request for software recommendations (the close votes were made before my edit). You can also make such edits instead of close voting / flagging if such an option is viable (if it doesn't require extremely drastic changes to the question).

Answer (score 1):

> All of the code would still be visible on the page, but there would be some visual separation between all the modules

Do it with comments (`/* ======== */` or whatever separator character you want)

> for example each module is displayed in a bordered container

For this, you'd actually need an extension. Stack Overflow is not really for software recommendations (see /help/on-topic #3).

> and you could easily see the module title.

Again, you can do this with comments.

> And the modules would be collapsible.

Use [region folding markers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding). Ex. for CSS, like "`/*#region*/`" and "`/*#endregion*/`". See the docs for how to use region folding markers in other languages.

Comment: Yes, comments are what I'm using now. Thanks for the tip about regional folding comments. Sorry about asking for software recommendations.